# Ribbon button for specific style in OneNote

Tags: button, office365, gallery, ribbon, onenote

I'm trying to add buttons on the Styles section of the Home ribbon for specific styles but the only options I can see are to add the gallery control.  Specifically I want "normal" and "code" buttons as I switch between these a lot but more generally the question would be how to create a ribbon button for any item within a gallery control.

Comment: You can review the following link for reference:https://superuser.com/questions/1200928/adding-a-custom-button-to-the-onenote-ribbon

Comment: Thanks for this.  Reading more about OneNote it seems it was developed somewhat in isolation from the rest of the Office suite which is why it is rather lacking in some of the customisation facilities and things like proper VBA support.  Even something simple as adding a new custom style is impossible without using a third party application.